# Trying to code my own 'partition' function in haskell

Tags: haskell

as the title says, I'm trying to recode this function but I keep getting an error that says that the type that I output doesnt match the expected type. Could someone help me with this? Here's my code :

```
myPartition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
myPartition f (x:xs) = if f x
    then (x : myPartition f xs, [])
    else ([], x : myPartition f xs)
myPartition _ [] = ([], [])
```

Also, im not authorized to use any function of the standard library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that your function checks if `f x` holds, and if so constructs a 2-tuple where it will write the *entire* result of the recursive call. That result will be a 2-tuple as well, so you try to use a 2-tuple as an element in a 2-tuple as an element in a …

You should make a recursive call to obtain a 2-tuple of elements for the rest of the list, and the prepend the item to any of the two, so:

```
myPartition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
myPartition p = go
  where go (x:xs)
          | p x = (…, …)
          | otherwise = (…, …)
          where (pa, pb) = go xs
        go [] = ([], [])
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` parts.

Comment: IIRC, `where ~(x,y) = ...` and `where (x,y) = ...` are equivalent. Patterns are already implicitly lazy in `where` and `let` (but not elsewhere).

Comment: @chi: yes, but when these want to return something, it will require to evaluate it, to "split" it in two. And `~(x, y)` and `(x, y)` are unfortunately not the same. For example `f ~(x, y) ~(a, b) = (a, b)` will work for `f undefined (1,2)`, but not if these are not irrefutable.